# linux bash not showing job messages

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I don't get job messages after typing kill to terminate process or to stop it. So I don't know whether my command is accepted or not. Why my bash not displaying messages after command kill?
I'm using Ubuntu 12 inside VirtualBox.

Comment: Are you running them as jobs in the current shell?

Comment: Sorry but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related sites, either http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com  (Unix & Linux).  Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions ... not a programming question, or did I miss that part?   To (possibly?) answer your question: bash will only give you feedback if the job you're killing is backgrounded and was running under the same instance of bash.

Answer (score 1):

If you're issuing `kill`, then you know the process ID(PID). Having the PID you can fetch a lot of information about the process, if it still exists.

For example, the following command will print bit masks for blocked, caught, ignored, and pending signals:

```
pid=1189
ps -p $pid -o blocked,caught,ignored,pending,s,args
```

See `man ps` for details. The output will look like this:

```
       BLOCKED           CAUGHT          IGNORED          PENDING S COMMAND
0000000000000000 0000000180010002 0000000001001000 0000000000000000 S /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/py
```

The command fails, if the process doesn't exist. You'll ask how do you know if the command fails, if it outputs nothing. Well, that's where you can check for the value of `$?` variable which contains exit status of the previous command. If it's non-zero, then the previous command failed. Example:

```
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo 'success'
```

Another way is to parse `/proc/$pid/status`:

```
grep -i sig /proc/$pid/status

SigQ:   0/15042
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000001001000
SigCgt: 0000000180010002
```

The bit masks are hexadecimal numbers. If bit number `N` is set, then the bit mask contains signal with number `N`(assuming the bit numbers start from 1).

Thus, having the signal number `signum` and a bit mask `m` we can find out whether the signal exists in the bit mask with the following formula(pseudo code):

```
exists = mask & (1 << signum - 1)
```

We shift `1`(0x1) to the left by `signum - 1` bits, then apply bitwise `AND` operation on `mask`. The result is non-zero, if the bit for `signum` is set.

I've written a Bash script which prints the number of pending, blocked, ignored, and caught signals for a PID.

**pidsig.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash -
declare -i pid
declare -A sigmap

pid=$1

# Construct an array from the list of signal names and numbers
a=( `kill -l | sed -r 's~[)\t ]+~ ~g'` )

# Build signal name-to-number map
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#a[@]} ]
do
  v=${a[$i]}

  (( ++i ))
  k=${a[$i]}

  sigmap[$k]=$v

  (( ++i ))
done

# Fetch signal info from /proc/$pid/status,
# then print how many times the process caught each type of signal.
grep -P '^Sig\w{3}' /proc/$pid/status | while read -r -a line
do
  title="${line[0]}"
  mask=${line[1]}

  echo "======== $title ($mask) ==========="

  for k in "${!sigmap[@]}"
  do
    signum=${sigmap[$k]}
    #echo "k: $k v: $signum"

    # convert mask to decimal number, save into $m
    let "m = 0x$mask"

    # shift 1 to the left by `signum - 1` bits
    num_caught=$(( $m & (1 << signum - 1) ))

    # ignore zeroes
    [ $num_caught -eq 0 ] || printf "%-14s%s\n" $k $num_caught
  done
done
```

Usage:

```
./pidsig.sh $pid
```

where `$pid` is the process number. Don't forget to make it executable: `chmod +x pidsig.sh`.

Output will be similar to the following

```
======== SigPnd: (0000000000000000) ===========
======== SigBlk: (0000000000000000) ===========
======== SigIgn: (0000000001001000) ===========
SIGXFSZ       16777216
SIGPIPE       4096
======== SigCgt: (0000000180010002) ===========
SIGCHLD       65536
SIGINT        2
```